point a domain name to a vm with internal IP
I have windows server 2022 with hyper-v installed.
I created a virtual machine with windows server 2022 OS also installed plesk control panel.
The virtual machine has an internal IP not a public one, the internal IP is: 192.168.0.100.
I need to point a domain name (e.g. domain.com) to the Virtual machine.
is that possible?
Thanks..

Is it your goal to make this VM accessible from the internet, or is it only for something on your computer or alternatively inside your network? Answering this question will determine all the steps you need to do to get it working.

the goal is to make the vm accessible from the internet not my local computer only.. I know that I can edit the hosts file to make it work from my computer.. but I want to domain to work on the vm and be accessible to the whole internet.. Thanks..

When a local pc needs to be accessible from the internet using IPv4, one always needs to use the public IP address. There are simply too few IP addresses available to be able to use the LAN IP address.
So in order to get the VM accessible from the internet, first, find out what the public IP address is by going to https://www.whatsmyip.com and note it down. I'm going to assume here that you are not behind a CGNAT.
Next, Change the DNS of the domain and set the A record to this IP address.
It can take up to 48 hours for DNS changes to be active everywhere.
Next, change the network adapter settings and set it to bridge or NAT. If you use NAT, add port 80 and 443 in the NAT table and test it from your pc first.
Next, In the router, allow port 80 and 443 to be forwarded to your PC if you use NAT or directly to the VM if you use bridge.
Next, make sure the firewall is setup correctly.
Lastly, Most routers will not support NAT hairpinning, which means that accessing domain.com will work from outside the network, but not from inside. To fix this, in the local DNS server, add an entry for your domain.com and set its A record to the LAN IP address.
Now domain.com will work from both outside the network and inside.
And before you say: But I only want to use the LAN IP because I can't access the router, then that means it will only work from inside the network. If IPv6 is possible, you don't need to setup NAT rules, but it will severely limit access to your server.
Also, if port 80 and/or 443 are not available, you can use a different port, but then the domain will become https://mydomain:4443, assuming we changed the port to 4443. The NAT rule on the router would then become 4443 -> 443 and the VM still uses 443.

Missing 2nd step – make sure the address from "whatismyip.com" is actually the address that OP's router shows as the "WAN" address. We've been having so many threads where it turns out that this is not the case and the author is behind CGNAT...

Hi, Thank you for your detailed answer .. but I don't have a router, it's a dedicated server from hetzner.com.. and yes I created a NAT network and routed some ports to some windows vms to use for remote desktop like this:

Add-NetNatStaticMapping -ExternalIPAddress "0.0.0.0/24" -ExternalPort 40040 -Protocol TCP -InternalIPAddress "192.168.0.100" -InternalPort 3389 -NatName NATNetwork

so do you mean that I should route the external ports 80 and 433 to the vm using the same command? one more question plz, when you talked about dns.. should I install a dns server on the parent windows server to create the dns entries you talked about? Thanks again..

Yes, you use the same way of port forwarding for ports 80 and 443. As for the DNS part, your domain comes with a control panel to handle DNS, you edit it there. So wherever you got the domain from, they will have a section somewhere that allows you to configure DNS records. If you got the domain from hetzner.com too, then there will also be a section that's called something like: "manage domains" -> "DNS records".

WORKED AS A CHARM :)))))))) THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU :)
